# How to run create-react-app on host 0.0.0.0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssl, networking

Update:
I have found the issue to be that create-react-app is never changing the host to 0.0.0.0. This is due to the network I'm running this on at work. If I remove 0.0.0.0 from the flask server, it gives the same errors. It only works with 0.0.0.0 as the hostname in Flask but I can't find any way to run the react server on it. It only ever runs on localhost:3001 and ip:3001, both of which give me errors with https.

I am having trouble launching the sample app from create-react-app and TLS 1.2+ are the only protocols supported on my work network.

I've made an .env file for React as below. However, Chrome says it's not a trusted certificate and won't load. Is there any way to force the protocol used with an env variable?

```
HTTPS=true
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=3001
SSL_CRT_FILE=file.cer
SSL_KEY_FILE=file.key
```

I had similar problems with my flask server but eventually got it to work as below

```
def ssl_setup():
  cer_file = file.cer
  key_file = file.key

  context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
  context.load_cert_chain(cer_file, key_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001, ssl_context=ssl_setup())
```

Using chrome dev tools, it shows that Flask is using AES256 while React is using AES128. Maybe this is the issue?

[image]

[image]

Forcing 256 bit is still not working, it keep saying my certificate is invalid even though it works just fine in Python. To force it I used `export NODE_OPTIONS=--tls-cipher-list=''ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:!RC4''`